# What is the correct way of checking the format of a String in Kotlin?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, format

I'm developing an app that reads serial numbers using Google MLkit's OCR.
I've found out that sometimes the readings are not totally accurate due to this I've created a function that returns true/false whenever the format is not correct. I'm kind of new to Kotlin and I am using a cuestionable way of doing so because I have failed to find any information on how to do this on a more efficient/correct way.

Serial numbers always have the same format. L=Letter D=Digit
Format: LDDLLDDDDDDL

I am sure there is a better way of doing this that does not involve a code pyramid of giza.

```
fun checkFormat(numSerie: String): Boolean {
    val numSerieArr = numSerie.toCharArray()
    var isCorrect = false
    if (numSerieArr[0].isLetter()) {
        if (numSerieArr[1].isDigit()) {
            if (numSerieArr[2].isDigit()) {
                if (numSerieArr[3].isLetter()) {
                    if (numSerieArr[4].isLetter()) {
                        if (numSerieArr[5].isDigit()) {
                            if (numSerieArr[6].isDigit()) {
                                if (numSerieArr[7].isDigit()) {
                                    if (numSerieArr[8].isDigit()) {
                                        if (numSerieArr[9].isDigit()) {
                                            if (numSerieArr[10].isDigit()) {
                                                    if (numSerieArr[11].isLetter()) {
                                                        isCorrect = true
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return isCorrect
}
```

Thanks in advance for any replies to this!

Comment: **Regular expressions** are most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: @Vym Thanks, looks like that's the way, i will update the post with the solution if I manage to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Regular Expressions for this

```
    fun checkFormat(numSerie: String): Boolean {
    val regex = Regex(
        pattern = "([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)",
        options = setOf(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    )
    return regex.matches(numSerie)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this for example:

```
fun checkFormat(numSerie: String): Boolean {
    val format = "LDDLLDDDDDDDL"
    if (numSerie.length != format.length) return false
    numSerie.forEachIndexed { index, c ->
        when (format[index]) {
            'L' -> if (!c.isLetter()) return false
            'D' -> if (!c.isDigit()) return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Although I agree with above comment that working with a regular expression is probably the best solution, but I don't know how to best write a solution using that.

Comment: Im going to try the Regular Expression aproach since it looks like it's the correct way, but this looks fine to me aswell